# Is this usage of unordered map efficient/right way?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I want to learn about mapping functions in c/c++ in general so this is a basic program on unordered mapping. I use unordered mapping because my input data are not sorted and I read that `unordered_map` is very efficient. Here I've an array with which I'm creating the hash table and use the `lookup` function to find if the elements in another array are in the hash table or not. I've several questions regarding this implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

typedef std::unordered_map<int,int> Mymap; 
int main()
{
int x,z,l=0;
int samplearray[5] = {0,6,4,3,8};
int testarray[10] = {6,3,8,67,78,54,64,74,22,77};

Mymap c1;

for ( x=0;x< sizeof(samplearray)/sizeof(int);x++)
 c1.insert(Mymap::value_type(samplearray[x], x));

for ( z=0;z< sizeof(testarray)/sizeof(int);z++)
 if((c1.find(testarray[z]) != c1.end()) == true)
  l++;

printf("The number of elements equal are : %d\n",l);
printf("the size of samplearray and testarray are : %d\t%d\n",sizeof(samplearray)/sizeof(int),sizeof(testarray)/sizeof(int));
}
```

1. First of all, is this a right way to
   implement it? I'm getting the
   answers right but seems that I use
   too much of for loop.
2. This seems fairly okay with very small data but if I'm dealing with files of size > 500MB then this seems that, if I create a hash table for a 500MB file then the size of the hash table itself will be twice as much which is 1000MB. Is this always the case?
3. What is the difference between std::unordered map and boost::unordered map?

Finally, a small request. I'm new to C/C++ so if you are giving suggestions like using some other typedef/libraries, I'd highly appreciate if you could use a small example or implement it on my code. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're starting off on the wrong foot. A `map` (ordered or otherwise) is intended to store a key *along with* some associated data. In your case, you're only storing a number (twice, as both the key and the data). For this situation, you want a `set` (again, ordered or otherwise) instead of a map.

I'd also avoid at least the first `for` loop, and use `std::copy` instead:

```
// There are better ways to do this, but it'll work for now:
#define end(array) ((array) + (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]))

std::copy(samplearray, 
          end(samplearray), 
          std::inserter(Myset));
```

If you *only* need to count how many items are common between the two sets, your for loop is fairly reasonable. If you need/want to actually know what items are common between them, you might want to consider using `std::set_intersection`:

```
std::set<int> myset, test_set, common;

std::copy(samplearray, end(samplearray), std::inserter(myset));
std::copy(testarray, end(testarray), std::inserter(test_set));

std::set_intersection(myset.begin(), myset.end(), 
                      test_set.begin(), test_set.end(), 
                      std::inserter(common));

// show the common elements (including a count):
std::cout <<common.size() << " common elements:\t";
std::copy(common.begin(), common.end(), 
          std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\t");
```

Note that you don't need to have an actual `set` to use `set_intersection` -- all you need is a sorted collection of items, so if you preferred to you could just sort your two arrays, then use `set_intersection` on them directly. Likewise, the result could go in some other collection (e.g., a `vector`) if you prefer.

Comment: Isn't range-constructing preferred (as in, `std::set<int> myset(samplearray, end(samplearray));`)?

Comment: @Cubbi: In the case of something like a vector, it's definitely preferred. In the case of a set, most such preference would be personal, not general. Depending on the source of the data, range-based construction often isn't suitable/possible though, and trying to teach when to use/avoid it would be a lot (probably too much) for a single answer...

Comment: @jerry: I actually want to count the items. Set intersection would be an costly operation on large files in the size of > 10GB because of the sort function. Is it not?

Comment: @jerry: Moreover searching an element on set seems to be logarithmic in size while unordered map is O(1), correct?

Comment: @Sunil: yes, if you just want a count, `set_intersection` probably isn't a good choice. Yes, operations on `set` are logarithmic and on unordered_* are constant -- but that doesn't necessarily mean much. If it is a problem for your situation, consider using `unordered_set` (which I'd intended to mention, but looking back, apparently didn't at least directly). Keep in mind, however, that `set` tends to be more friendly to virtual memory than `unordered_set`, so if you're reaching the limits of memory, it may work better.

Comment: @jerry: the copy line in your program works only when its like this `std::copy(samplearray, end(samplearray), std::inserter(myset),myset.end());`. Is this right? My concern is I do not see how the `myset.end()` works because when we start to inserting the first element the begin and the end are the same. If we are searching or doing someother operation I can understand the reason but why when insertion?

Comment: @Sunil: Oops, yes, you're quite right that it needs that final parameter (though it should be: `std::inserter(myset, myset.end())`). As to why it needs it: mostly because they never provided an overload specifically for associative containers, and with a sequence it really needs to know where you want to insert the new items.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Jerry, you could use a `for` loop for the search if you only need to know the number of matches. If that is the case, I would recommend using an `unordered_set` since you don't need the elements to be sorted.

Comment: Why would anybody use `unordered_map` when they have `unordered_set` doing the same function with a lesser space?